# graphics before the title in a0poster class

Tags: titles, include, a0poster

I would like to add the logo of my institute before the title page (center aligned).   I tried to add inside the title, but it did not work

I tried this, but no success

```
\begin{textblock}{14}[0.5,0](12,0)
  \title[Article]{\includegraphics{Lax}~ \\[2ex] Methods for Blah}
  \author{\begin{center}
          \hfill Name Surname
          \hfill\phantom{.}\\[1ex]
          University Name
          \end{center}
          } \\[-3ex] \\
  \end{textblock}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the logo to the left of the title, then try this:

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Methods for Blah}
\author{Name Surname\\University Name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{0}(0,0)
\noindent\includegraphics{Lax}
\end{textblock}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you want your logo above the title, stretching the width of the text, then try this:

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Lax}\\Methods for Blah}
\author{Name Surname\\University Name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Now that your requirements are more clear, I am happy to delete this answer (or have it deleted) if something better comes along.

Comment: It gives me error  \begin{document}

I added the begin{document} after  the title and author.

Comment: your code is not compiling.

Comment: here is my code.  http://mathb.in/91079

Comment: Ok. This should work right ?.  http://mathb.in/91106  It is also not compiling.

Comment: Ok.  I got it.  But unfortunately, with your code, the title and author is not below the graphics. I want the title and other details below the logo (My logo should span the whole poster, and below should be the title and details)